# why is 5 the default number of connections in the rails database connection pool?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails defaults to 5 connections in the database pool.  I've always wondered why this is the case.  Is it significantly more performant than just 1 or 2?

Comment: If you have 10 worker threads, then I imagine, yes, it's more performant.

Comment: Looks like my question is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086880/correct-setting-of-database-connection-pool-database-yml-for-single-threaded-rai.  As in that question, I'm just wondering if it matters for single-threaded performance at all.