# Actioncable: Puma caught this error: could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I'm getting this specific error when working on local (C9.io, haven't tried live yet). It happens when a lot of users are using my chat conversation.

ALSO, i noticed that when i'm working for a while on the platform...the CPU level sky rockets. What can cause this?

```
Puma caught this error: could not obtain a connection from the pool within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.022 seconds); all pooled connections were in use (ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:202:in `block in wait_poll'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:193:in `loop'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:193:in `wait_poll'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:154:in `internal_poll'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:278:in `internal_poll'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:148:in `block in poll'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:158:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:148:in `poll'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:709:in `acquire_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:501:in `checkout'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:364:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:875:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:128:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:91:in `connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:39:in `block in register_hook'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `block in make_lambda'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:547:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `catch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:546:in `block in default_terminator'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:170:in `block in halting'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_run_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:99:in `run!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:61:in `block in run!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:58:in `tap'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:58:in `run!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:10:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-cors-0.4.0/lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-cors-0.4.0/lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:415:in `process_client'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.6.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a scaling issue. Try increasing the ActiveRecord pool size as suggested in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086880/correct-setting-of-database-connection-pool-database-yml-for-single-threaded-rai).

As for the CPU usage. Almost no way to determine without seeing the code. And even then it's going to be difficult. Try monitoring tools like NewRelic to see where the CPU intensive parts are.

Comment: Is there negativity behind increasing the ActiveRecord pool size?

Comment: It uses more resources. Heroku hast a good article about that: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections.